# TryDequeue an unknown value in C# from an otherwise ever-growing ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#

I have declared a `ConcurrentQueue` and will be enqueuing all the data points from an external source in a while loop. Is there a way to remove the first element when the queue size is over a certain number, say 100?
Thanks!

Comment: How is it unknown if `<T>` is known when you create the queue? What is the problem with using `TryDequeue`?

Comment: Probably the best solution is to implement your own Queue where the data structure behind the scenes is a circular buffer. that would do the trick and is not too hard.

Comment: There is nothing special in `ConcurrentQueue` that facilitates this. Who is reading, who is writing? You can always use an event (or a monitor) to have a producer wake up a consumer on any arbitrary condition (like the queue count exceeding 100).

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is not a Queue but a Circular/Ring Buffer.

I do not know of a built-in .NET/C# implementation, but the basic idea is to have a fixed-size storage with separate indexes and semaphores for adding and removing elements.

With the Concurrent Collections, best you can do is BlockingCollection, which waits for free space or available elements, blocking either readers or writers.